# Applying Platt Scaling to One Class SVM for probability scoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, svm, spyder

I have trained a one class SVM and fit new data to the model. I'm looking for a way to generate probability scores for the output and seeing there is not a built in way, only a decision function. 
Is Platt Scaling the easiest way to go about this. I have found literature about Platt Scaling but not much on implementing the code in Python.

I tried something like this, but my output is still just showing 0s and 1s

```
def platt_scale(clf, X, train_size, cv_size):
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)

    X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X, y_pred, train_size=train_size)

    lr = LRCV(cv=cv_size)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

   return lr.predict_proba(X)

array = platt_scale(clf, X2, .3, 3)
```

Comment: What type of support vector machine are you using? `SVC`?

Comment: @jcaliz svm.OneClassSVM with polynomial kernel

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?